# Functional inequality under mean curvature flow

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, geometry

Let $\Sigma$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\Sigma_t$ be a variation of $\Sigma$ under the mean curvature flow under an extra condition that ${\rm vol}_{n-1}(\Sigma)={\rm vol}_{n-1}(\Sigma_t)$, $t>0$. I was wondering if there is any result considering how the Poincaré constant on $\Sigma_t$ evolves (possibly for $t$ small enough).